# Python streaming with mplayer

Tags: python, youtube, mplayer, assistant, pafy

Hey everyone this is my first question so I apologize for any formatting errors/ignorance. 
I'm working on a personal assistant and I want it to stream youtube videos (audio only). I've managed to get it to find the url of the first video of a search term, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get mplayer to stream that url. I'm using pafy and [this](https://code.google.com/p/python-mplayer/) mplayer wrapper.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re
import pafy
import os
import mplayer
import subprocess


query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : input()})
html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)
search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
url = ("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0])

v = pafy.new(url)
print(v.audiostreams)
s = v.getbestaudio()
```

This is the code to get the url and create a pafy instance. I'd greatly appreciate any help you guys could offer in streaming it to mplayer. Thanks!